# Docker Compose, Postgres and Python Connection Refused

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I have a python code that connects to postgresql and writes data. However when I containerise it, python code is unable to connect to postgresql.
Provide below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy

username = 'user1'
password = '12345'
host_name = 'pgdatabase'
port = '5433'
database_name = 'traindb'

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host_name}:{port}/{database_name}')
df=pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
df.to_sql(name='cleandata', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

and the yaml code is below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pgdatabase:
    container_name: pgdatabase
    image: postgres:12-bullseye
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
      - POSTGRES_DB=traindb
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    volumes:
      - "./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  cleandata:
    build: "."
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    depends_on:
      - pgdatabase
networks:
  postgres_network:
    external: false
```

Help me please for my problem.

The error received is "psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused".

Answer (score 1):

You are using the service name as the `hostname` of the database, but internally the database is listening on port `5432`. So you have to use either `pgdatabase:5432` or `localhost:5433` (as you have already forwarded the port `5432` from the container to `5433` on host machine).

If you use the service name, you have to use the "actual" port the container is exposed to. If you forward that port, you can then use `localhost` along with the forwarded port. I hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `pgdatabase:5432` is worked.